# Not allow any other application to open except a browser

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, jakarta-ee, browser

I am presently working on website (Java EE).  One of the requirements is to not let the client to open anything else other than the browser.  After a lot of search I got the following results :

1. Change the policy of the OS.
2. Write some batch/c/c++ program which will intercept all the keyboard and mouse events not letting the user open anything else.

PS : It should work on windows and IE 7 or above only.  The other OS and browsers need not be considered. This software is made only for intranet, so I already have control on the client machines if I have to run something.

My question is .. is there anything else I can do which will reduce the work needed on the client side or on the program which I have to write??

Comment: In a corporate environment you'd usually lock this down using system policy, which is the only real solution anyway, since the system controls the processes that are launched. Sounds more like a sysadmin question than a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is very OS specific I'd say. Windows, I believe, has APIs related to finding open windows. You could find all open windows and close them. In your application's main loop you can detect if any windows are open then close them.

Perhaps mac and ubuntu have something similar.

This might be a good place to start looking: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx

I have no idea how to use it though.

You'll need something more powerful than javascript to communicate with your application that is monitoring the user's desktop. You may want to look at connecting JS to Silverlight then having the client download something upon opening the browser that is also similar to silverlight or .net. Then you can have them all communicate possibly.

Comment: This is just a best guess though.

Comment: @paris : I din't want it to be solved using javascript as I knew javascript is not powerful enough to control the OS operations .. will definitely look into that link you have posted ..

Answer (score 0):

You can set IE to be the shell process (a registry key) instead of explorer.exe, and then run IE in [kiosk mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780), and then disable task manager via policy (to prevent new processes).

Comment: It still doesn't block me to open any other application .. I can alt+tab and do anything .. we will have to use key hooks to capture these and then return false on these action. Even after we do this ctrl+alt+del will not be captured as it directly communicates with the hardware ..